Access folders and content contained by dropbox namespace
I have a Dropbox account that is linked to a team.  The folder structure resembles this:
/[My Name]
  /Lorem Ipusm
  ...
/My Company Team Folder
  /Topics
    /Topic A
      - File A
      - File B
    /Topic B
      - File C
      - File D
  /Something Else
  ...

I'm trying to access the Topics folder, its children, and their content.
Making a POST to /2/team/token/get_authenticated_admin gets the ID values that I need for subsequent queries:
{
    "admin_profile": {
        "team_member_id": "ABCEDF",
        ...
        "root_folder_id": "1"
    }
}

Making a POST to /2/files/list_folder, setting Dropbox-API-Select-User=ABCEDF and Dropbox-API-Path-Root={".tag": "root", "root": "1"}, lists the two parent folders:
{
    "entries": [
        {
            ".tag": "folder",
            "name": "[My Name]",
            "parent_shared_folder_id": "1",
            ...
        },
        {
            ".tag": "folder",
            "name": "My Company Team Folder",
            "parent_shared_folder_id": "1",
            "shared_folder_id": "2",
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}

Making a POST to /2/team/namespaces/list lists the namespace that I need:
{
    "namespaces": [
        {
            "name": "My Company Team Folder",
            "namespace_id": "2",
            "namespace_type": {
                ".tag": "team_folder"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Topics"
            "namespace_id": "3",
            "namespace_type": {
                ".tag": "shared_folder"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Something Else"
            "namespace_id": "4",
            "namespace_type": {
                ".tag": "shared_folder"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to list the contents of the Topics folder.
I've tried making a POST to /2/files/list_folder, with a Dropbox-API-Path-Root of {".tag": "root", "root": "3"}, but this returns an invalid_root error.
What am I missing?

Found my answer:
Send a POST to /2/files/list_folder with header:

Dropbox-Api-Select-Admin = ABCEDF

and body:
{
    "path": "ns:3",
    "recursive": true
}

results:
{
    "entries": [
        {
            ".tag": "folder",
            "name": "Topic A",
            ...
        },
        {
            ".tag": "file",
            "name": "File A",
            ...
        },
    ]
}

